# Modifying binary during execution

Tags: linux, binary

I often come across the situation when developing, where I am running a binary file, say `a.out` in the background as it does some lengthy job. While it's doing that, I make changes to the C code which produced `a.out` and compile `a.out` again. So far, I haven't had any problems with this. The process which is running `a.out` continues as normal, never crashes, and always runs the old code from which it originally started.

However, say `a.out` was a huge file, maybe comparable to the size of the RAM. What would happen in this case? And say it linked to a shared object file, `libblas.so`, what if I modified `libblas.so` during runtime? What would happen?

My main question is - does the OS guarantee that when I run `a.out`, then the original code will always run normally, as per the *original* binary, regardless of the size of the binary or `.so` files it links to, even when those `.o` and `.so` files are modfied during runtime?

I know there are these questions that address similar issues:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506865/when-a-binary-file-runs-does-it-copy-its-entire-binary-data-into-memory-at-once
[What happens if you edit a script during execution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88487/what-happens-if-you-edit-a-script-during-execution)
[How is it possible to do a live update while a program is running?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138214/how-is-it-possible-to-do-a-live-update-while-a-program-is-running?lq=1)

Which have helped me understand a bit more about this but I don't think that they are asking exactly what I want, which is a general rule for the consequences of *modifying a binary during execution*

Comment: To me, the questions you linked (especially the Stack Overflow one) already provide significant help in understanding these consequences (or absence thereof). Since the kernel loads your program into memory *text regions/segments*, it should not be affected by changes made through the file subsystem.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith On Stackoverflow, the top answer says `if they are read-only copies of something already on disc (like an executable, or a shared object file), they just get de-allocated and are reloaded from their source`, so I got the impression that if your binary is huge, then if part of your binary goes out of RAM, but is then needed again it is "reloaded from source" - so any changes in the `.(s)o` file will be reflected during execution. But of course I may have misunderstood - which is why I am asking this more specific question

Comment: @JohnWHSmith Also the second answer says `No, it only loads the necessary pages into memory. This is demand paging.` So I was actually under the impression that what I asked for cannot be guaranteed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While the Stack Overflow question seemed to be enough at first, I understand, from your comments, why you may still have a doubt about this. To me, this is exactly the kind of *critical situation* involved when the two UNIX subsystems (processes and files) communicate.

As you may know, UNIX systems are usually divided into two subsystems: the file subsystem, and the process subsystem. Now, unless it is instructed otherwise through a system call, the kernel should not have these two subsystems interact with one another. There is however one exception: the loading of an executable file into a process' *text regions*. Of course, one may argue that this operation is also triggered by a system call (`execve`), but this is usually known to be the *one* case where the process subsystem makes an implicit request to the file subsystem.

Because the process subsystem naturally has no way of handling files (otherwise there would be no point in dividing the whole thing in two), it has to use whatever the file subsystem provides to access files. This also means that the process subsystem is submitted to whatever measure the file subsystem takes regarding file edition/deletion. On this point, I would recommend reading [Gilles' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138241/41892) to [this U&L question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/138214/41892). The rest of my answer is based on this more general one from Gilles.

The first thing that should be noted is that internally, files are only accessible through *inodes*. If the kernel is given a path, its first step will be to translate it into a inode to be used for all other operations. When a process loads an executable into memory, it does it through its inode, which has been provided by the file subsystem after translation of a path. Inodes may be associated to several paths (links), and programs may only delete links. In order to delete a file and its inode, userland must remove all existing links to that inode, and ensure that it is completely unused. When these conditions are met, the kernel will automatically delete the file from disk.

If you have a look at the **replacing executables** part of Gilles' answer, you'll see that depending on *how you edit/delete* the file, the kernel will react/adapt differently, always through a mechanism implemented within the file subsystem.

- If you try strategy one (*open/truncate to zero/write* or *open/write/truncate to new size*), you'll see that the kernel won't bother handling your request. You'll get an error 26: *Text file busy* (`ETXTBSY`). No consequences whatsoever.
- If you try strategy two, the first step is to delete your executable. However, since it is being used by a process, the file subsystem will kick in and prevent the file (and its inode) from being *truly* deleted from disk. From this point, the only way to access the old file's content is to do it through its inode, which is what the process subsystem does whenever it needs to load new data into *text sections* (internally, there is no point in using paths, except when translating them into inodes). Even though you've *unlinked* the file (removed all its paths), the process can still use it as if you'd done nothing. Creating a new file with the old path doesn't change anything: the new file will be given a completely new inode, which the running process has no knowledge of.

> Strategies 2 and 3 are safe for executables as well: although running executables (and dynamically loaded libraries) aren't open files in the sense of having a file descriptor, they behave in a very similar way. As long as some program is running the code, the file remains on disk even without a directory entry.

- Strategy three is quite similar since the `mv` operation is an atomic one. This will probably require the use of the `rename` system call, and since processes can't be interrupted while in kernel mode, nothing can interfere with this operation until it completes (successfully or not). Again, there is no alteration of the old file's inode: a new one is created, and already-running processes will have no knowledge of it, even if it's been associated with one of the old inode's links.

> With strategy 3, the step of moving the new file to the existing name removes the directory entry leading to the old content and creates a directory entry leading to the new content. This is done in one atomic operation, so this strategy has a major advantage: if a process opens the file at any time, it will either see the old content or the new content — there's no risk of getting mixed content or of the file not existing.

**Recompiling a file** : when using `gcc` (and the behaviour is probably similar for many other compilers), you are using strategy 2. You can see that by running a `strace` of your compiler's processes:

```
stat("a.out", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0750, st_size=8511, ...}) = 0
unlink("a.out") = 0
open("a.out", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
chmod("a.out", 0750) = 0
```

- The compiler detects that the file already exists through the `stat` and `lstat` system calls.
- The file is *unlinked*. Here, while it is no longer accessible through the name `a.out`, its inode and contents remain on disk, for as long as they are being used by already-running processes.
- A new file is created and made executable under the name `a.out`. This is a brand new inode, and brand new contents, which already-running processes don't care about.

Now, when it comes to shared libraries, the same behaviour will apply. As long as a library object is used by a process, it will not be deleted from disk, no matter how you change its links. Whenever something has to be loaded into memory, the kernel will do it through the file's inode, and will therefore ignore the changes you made to its links (such as associating them with new files).

Comment: Fantastic, detailed answer. That explains my confusion. So am I correct in assuming that because the inode is still available, the data from the original binary file is still on the disk and so using `df` to work out the number of free bytes on the disk is wrong as it doesn't take inodes  which have all *filesystem links* removed taken into account? So I should use `df -i`? (This is just a technical curiosity, I don't really need to know the exact disk usage!)

Comment: Just to clarify for future readers - my confusion was that I thought on execution, the whole binary would be loaded into RAM, so if RAM was small, then part of the binary would leave the RAM and have to be reloaded from disk - which would cause problems if you changed the file. But the answer has made it clear that the binary is never really removed from disk even if you `rm` or `mv` it as the inode to the original file is not removed until all processes remove their link to that inode.

Comment: @texasflood Exactly. Once all paths have been removed, no new process (`df` included) can get information about the inode. Whatever new information you find is related to the new file, and to the new inode. The main point here is that the process subsystem has no interest in this problem, so the notions of memory management (demand paging, process swapping, page faults, ...) are completely irrelevant. This is a file subsystem problem, and it is taken care of by the file subsystem. The process subsystem does not bother with that, that's not what it's here for.

Comment: @texasflood A note about `df -i`: this tool probably retrieves information from the fs' superblock, or its cache, meaning that it may include the inode of the old binary (for which all links have been deleted). This does not mean that new processes are free to use that old data, though.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that due to memory mapping of a running process, the kernel would not allow updating a reserved portion of the mapped file. I guess in case a process is running then all of its file is reserved hence updating it because you compiled a new version of your source actually results in creating a new set of inodes. In short, the older version(s) of your executable remain(s) accessible on the disk through page fault events. So even if you update a huge file, it *should* remain accessible and the kernel *should* still see the untouched version for as long as the process is running. The original file inodes *should not* be reused for as long as the process is running.

This of course has to be confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

This is not always the case when replacing a .jar file. Jar resources and some runtime reflection class loaders are not read from disk until the program explicitly requests the information.

This is only an issue because a jar is simply an archive rather than a single executable that gets mapped into memory. This is slightly off-stopic but is still an offshoot of your question and something I've shot myself in the foot with.

So for executables: yes. For jar files: maybe (depending on implementation).