# update during execution

Tags: bash, git

I have a bash script in a git repo. I used `git pull` inside the script to update. But sometimes, when I do changes to the script itself, the whole script crashes because it is changed during execution. I want something to update this file but not during the execution.

How could I do this??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens if you edit a script during execution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/88487)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Universal way**

One of the common way to solve such problem is to have two versions of the script - one to run, another to store in repository. It works for any version control system, and even if the script is downloaded from the web.

For example, you can have `update.sh.in` (add it to repository):

```
#!/bin/bash
git pull
if [ update.sh.in -nt update.sh ]; then cp update.sh.in update.sh; fi

# actual work of the script
# any line here can be changed in the next version of the script
```

Manually copy that file into `update.sh`, include it into `.gitignore`. Run the `update.sh`.

The trick here is that the first three lines should not be modified. As long as the copy of `.sh.in` into `.sh` remain in the same position of the script - it can be run without a problem.

The `.in` extension is a traditional extension for various tools which generate actual script or source code from template files.

**GIT hooks**

Another, also common, but maybe less so, way: is to use git hooks. That is a GIT-specific approach. You can write additional scripts and put them inside `.git/hooks` directory. Git will call these scripts in various points of execution.

You did not specify what exactly do you need to do beside `git pull`. But probably, you can put your special work into `.git/hooks/pre-rebase` or `.git/hook/post-merge`. which are called automatically for `git pull`.

For full list of hooks read here: https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks

Comment: See also the 2nd half of Stéphane's answer here: [What happens if you edit a script during execution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88497). This may be simpler?